# web widget and SEO

Tags: html, iframe, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How good is it for SEO if you have a widget that lives on other sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/how-good-is-it-for-seo-if-you-have-a-widget-that-lives-on-other-sites)

I'm designing a voting widget that other people can put on their websites, and the widget will have links to my site (partly for functionality and partly for SEO).

I'd like to design the widget such that my main [website](http://www.OpenSTV.org), gets the SEO benefits, and I'm not sure which techniques for designing a widget would accomplish that.  Here is what I am thinking:

- Creating a widget defined by `<div>` tags that people would embed in their web page -- This seems certain to give my site the SEO benefits, but it seems like it might be more work for the person using the widget to get it to work right and look nice.
- Using an iframe -- I think that the iframe link would get the SEO benefit and not my website, which would be linked to from the contents of the iframe.
- Google Gadget -- I don't know how this works yet.

What would be the best way to design a web widget to maximize the SEO benefits for my website?

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment relating to the vote to close.

Comment: The close votes are migrating your question to the Webmasters SE site.

Comment: This question is similar and has a good answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/how-good-is-it-for-seo-if-you-have-a-widget-that-lives-on-other-sites

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the first approach.

The `<iframe>` just seems overkill and the Google Gadgets approach loads the Widget via a `<script>` tag in the `<body>`, which won't be compatible with Google's web crawler.

Comment: Although concise, this answer has info not present in the answers to questions of which this is a duplicate.