# How do I get the word out about my site?

Tags: marketing, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)

This has plagued me for a long time now. I just can't seem to grasp internet marketing very well.

I recently started a website to help people with anxiety, now I just have no idea how to make people aware of it.

The website is free and doesn't even have ads. I don't have the money to put into Adwords right now...I've asked people to link my site but nobody wants to because they think it will take away from their own visits.

How can I bring more hits to my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is engage.  You have to engage with potential readers by doing something like:

1. go to forums about anxiety and comment
2. go to blogs about anxiety and comment
3. set-up some google alerts for anxiety and see other news about anxiety
4. set-up an rss for the word anxiety on twitter - and respond to appropriate people