# How to increase visitors of my Website per day

Tags: seo, php, search-engines, google-search-console, visitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)

My website is fully implemented with `SEO` and registered in all webmaster tool like of *Google,Bing,Yahoo* etc..

As result,
   **500 pages** of my website are listed in Google and lots of images as well.

There is **google site-links** are available of my Website.

Thought my website does not have more than 100 visitors per day(By Google Analytic)

So what to do to increase visitors of my website.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of stuff you can do (or change). For instance:

- **SEO**: are you using the right keywords. I.e: keywords people are actually using?
- **Partnerships**: do you have any partnerships within your industry/niche?
- **SEA**: have you considered using Search Engine Advertising programs such as Google Adwords to drive more traffic to your website?
- **Social Media**: are you (correctly) using Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn?
- **Email marketing*: are you using email marketing to get more returning visitors?
- **Concept**: what kind of website do you have? Do you have attractive content? Content someone will share with others?

You can think of a ton of activities you can enploy to drive more traffic to your website. I would encourage you to check them all out. Getting indexed in Search Engines is just the first step in the process to grow a website. To develop yourself I would recommend reading a lot about online marketing to learn more about all the wonderful options you have to get more traffic.