# How to promote travel blog?

Tags: blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)
>   [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)

I know this question might seem a little off topic, but blogging may become important part of travel.

Nowadays, in time of Facebook, Twitter and similar services, keeping a travel blog may seem a little *archaic*. It's not 2005 anymore. But a lot of my travel colleagues update their blogs and have significant number of readers.

I also tried to keep my blog when I travel. However it seems that the only reader is my mum ;)

**What is your advice on promoting a *travel* blog?**

Comment: "I know this question might seem a little off topic, but blogging may become important part of travel". you are right but I do not think this is the right place to learn how to promote your blog.. sorry.

Comment: @HaLaBi - "but I do not think this is the right place to learn how to promote your blog" he's not -- there is no URL to it.

Comment: @Christofian fair point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ideas:

- Submit to blog directories
- Comment on other regional, travel and lifestyle blogs
- Offer to write guest posts on other regional, travel, and lifestyle blogs
- Write "pillar posts", list posts, and other linkbait style articles for submission to social link aggregators
- Upload your travel photographs to appropriate photo sharing sites, with crosslinks to your blog
- Write particularly useful and interesting things