# My website not getting any traffic, How to get traffic?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)

I have done pretty nice SEO of my website , the website is made in php , anyone can submit article and the submitted articles are moderated by the moderators , the site is online from more then a month but still the user count is 10-20 only total impressions are 700 according to webmaster google , how much time does google webmaster takes to refresh the data , cause from 3 -4 days the impressions shown in the dashboard are 700 only , I am posting 2 article each day , please help me , I am very disappointed with all my effort and i really need a good motivation to carry on my work.
Please help my website url is http://www.viewloud.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some pagerank. To get pagerank, you need a lot of links to your website from websites with the same category, and high pagerank.

Second, marketing! You need to promote your website a lot to get people to visit your site, and hopefully return to you site is they like it.

And a month is nothing, it takes years for most websites to grow big. If your content is unique and visitors like your site you will succeed.

And if things on your website don't work, don't show them. It is very annoying if you click something and the message "sorry still in development" pops up.

Comment: thanks a lot john you were great help, i really needed a guidance and you showed me the path ! thanks a lot ....i will surely resolve them.
is there any personal contact info of yours where i can ask more to you ?