# How can I increase traffic to my website?

Tags: seo, traffic, web-traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)

I developed a site with CMS wordpress, I am currently in the phase referencing, I would like to know how I can have to increase traffic for site visits.

Answer (score 1):

Post good--quality content and get backlinks from other sites.